# A $\sigma$-compact space is second category iff the set of points at which $X$ is locally compact is non-empty

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that: A $\sigma$-compact space is second category if and only if the set of points at which $X$ is locally compact is non-empty, where $\sigma$-compact means that the space $X$ can be written as countable union of compact subsets, and $X$ is said to be locally compact at $x\in X$ if $x$ has a compact nbd in $X$.

I was trying to prove using contradiction.

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: I reminded you earlier also, please show some of your effort when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

The result is false if $X$ is not Hausdorff. Let $X=\Bbb N$ with the topology

$$\tau=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}\;,$$

where $U_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k\ge n\}$. Every set $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ is compact: if $a=\min A$, any open cover of $A$ must include some $U_n$ with $n\le a$, and $\{U_n\}$ is then a finite subcover. Thus, $X$ is locally compact at every point and is certainly $\sigma$-compact. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $F_n=X\setminus U_n$; then each $F_n$ is a closed set with empty interior and is therefore nowhere dense, and $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$, so $X$ is meagre (i.e., not second category) in itself. I will therefore assume henceforth that all spaces under consideration are Hausdorff.

---

Let $X$ be $\sigma$-compact, and suppose that $X$ is locally compact at $x$. Let $K$ be a compact nbhd of $x$. If $X$ is not second category in itself, then there is a family $\{G_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of dense open subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}G_n=\varnothing$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=G_n\cap K$; then $U_n$ is a dense open subset of the compact Hausdorff space $K$. Use the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space#Baire_category_theorem) to show that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n\ne\varnothing$; why does this show that $X$ is second category in itself?

Now suppose that no point of $X$ has a compact nbhd. Let $X=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n$, where each $K_n$ is compact. $X$ is Hausdorff, so each $K_n$ is closed.

- Why does each $K_n$ have empty interior?
- How does this show that $X$ is meagre (not second category) in itself?

Comment: I think a direct argument, "if $X$ is of the second category in itself, and $X = \bigcup K_n$, then some $K_n$ must have nonempty interior" is easier to follow here.

Comment: @Daniel: Then for you it probably is; that’s no guarantee that it will be for someone else. For me they’re much of a muchness, though what I wrote is how I actually saw it.

Comment: Sure. Different people have different viewpoints. I just put it there as an alternative.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: How is U_n dense in the proof?

Comment: @manisha: $U_n$ is dense in $K$ because $G_n$ is dense in $X$.